# Add-on for saving in .mht file format

Tags: security

I'd like to save web pages in .mht file format using Tor Browser  (https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/mozilla-archive-format/)

But installing additional addons or plugins into the Tor Browser is not recommended.

Would this specific one affect Tor's anonymity and privacy?

Answer (score 1):

> Would this specific one affect Tor's anonymity and privacy?

There's no real way of knowing in advance, without looking at the source code. If the source code isn't available - i.e. if it isn't an open-source project - then there's no way to check.

[Note that this does appear to be in an open format, but I can't immediately see where the code is kept. You'd either a) have to trust Mozilla, or b) find the code and go through it.]

The problem is twofold:

- The add-on could be creating its own connections to the outside world, bypassing Tor completely. If it can do this, then it can expose your real IP address.
- By installing add-ons and extensions, you change your browser's fingerprint, making you stand out from the rest of the crowd of Tor users. (See other posts marked with the [fingerprint](/questions/tagged/fingerprint) tag to get a better understanding of this.)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and suggestion, I'll try to  find the code and go through it, if possible.